# UserPrincipal GetAuthorizationGroups Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I've got a c# asp.net project, and I'm using the ADRoleProvider from CodeProject.com. My issue is with GetAuthorizationGroups. I understand that it's the recursive brother of GetGroups. I need that recursive-ness. However, it seems to check a cache/token before heading out to AD to get the list. While I appreciate it, I'd rather have it hit AD. I can't seem to figure out where that role cache is. Initially I was using:

```
Roles.DeleteCookie();
```

But that had no effect. Then I removed the use of a cookie for the role provider in the web.config. I figured that would be it, no cookie anymore. Nope, still not right.

Essentially, at this point I am running GetGroups vs. GetAuthorizationGroups and adding/removing myself from AD groups and you can see in real time that one list is current (GetGroups) the other is on what appears to be an unknown delay (GetAuthorizationGroups).

Is the next step sending some no-cache headers? I'd rather crush this at user login and force a current list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a similar [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/415588/userprincipal-getauthorizationgroups-returns-cached-non-existent-group-memberships-userprincipal-getgroups-works) was filed on this a long time ago on Microsoft Connect. No workarounds have been provided. If you need fresh AD data, it may be best to stick with GetGroups.